# Chern Character Isomorphism for non-CW complexes

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

Atiyah and Hirzebruch showed in their paper "Vector bundles and homogeneous spaces" that $\mathrm{K}^\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathrm{H}^\ast(X; \mathbb{Q})$, where $\mathrm{H}^\ast$ denotes singular cohomology, if $X$ is a finite CW complex.

Somewhere on the Internet I saw the statement $\mathrm{K}^\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \check{\mathrm{H}} {}^\ast(X; \mathbb{Q})$, where $\check{\mathrm{H}} {}^\ast$ denotes Cech cohomology, if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

> First, I'm looking for a reference for this fact $\mathrm{K}^\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \check{\mathrm{H}} {}^\ast(X; \mathbb{Q})$.
>
> Second, can the statements be extended to non-compact spaces, i.e., do we have something like $\mathrm{K}_{\text{cpt}}^\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathrm{H}_{\text{cpt}}^\ast(X; \mathbb{Q})$ for (locally finite) CW complexes? Or something analogous for the Cech cohomology and locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Posted this question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131341/

Comment: I have found an answer on myself and posted it on MO.